# Pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported

Tags: next.js, vercel

I think i am making some kind of confusion here.

According to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering), if i want Server Side Rendering (SSR) for the page i export the async function:

```
getServerSideProps
```

But if i do that i can't build the project for running either locally or now Zeit now.
If i try build or deploy i get:

> Error for page /_error: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export

The link provided by the error says i can't export. But I used the example from the documentation below:

```
import React from "react"

export async function getServerSideProps() {
        return { props: {  } }
}

function Page({ data }) {
    // Render data...
}

export default Page
```

Do i have to change some configuration somewhere?

How to prevent from building this static page?

Comment: You can't use server-side rendering (`getServerSideProps`) when statically exporting a Next.js app with `next export`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Won´t work on page _error.js, by design decision, as posted [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/11945#discussioncomment-6790) by nextjs maintenance staff.

One possibility is to use `getInitialProps`, instead.

Comment: But Next Js is recommending not to use `getInitialProps` https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Answer (score 5):

`getStaticProps()` is the way to go under the following conditions:

> - The data required to render the page is available at build time ahead of a user’s request
> - The data comes from a headless CMS
> - The data can be publicly cached (not user-specific)
> - The page must be pre-rendered (for SEO) and be very fast — getStaticProps generates HTML and JSON files, both of which can be cached by a CDN for performance

Refer here for when to use `getStaticProps` vs `getServerSideProps`

- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props
  vs:
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with that for a couple hours.

Here you can see the documentation that talks about this, but I will explain what I did also:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export

So in my case, the error was that I was trying to run this command when building the app: `next build && next export`. The command `next export` can only be used when you have static pages in all your project.
This can also happen if you have in your `next.config.js` file the property `output: "export"` set.

So the solution for me was removing `next export` from my build command and that's it. Basically, don't try to build as static pages your app when you use `getServerSideProps` because that requires SSR so it is no longer a static app.

In the documentation they also say that if you have pages using `getStaticProps` or no lifecycle, these will remain being static.

Hopefully this will save time to someone :)