# NextJS Static HTML export and hosting it in IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, next.js, static-site

I am facing problem in Microsoft's IIS deployment, By deploying "next export"'s static HTML generation code in the server.

The Code runs all okay, I can visit all the different pages by clicking the links in the HTML document. But if I manually copy the link and paste it in the browser's url bar it is showing me the following error

[image]

I have the live example hosted,
[Click Here](https://beta.amarstock.com/)

If we traverse to another page through the home page then it will not cause any problem.
But if we manually insert *"beta.amarstock.com/chart"* in the browser's url bar then it
is displaying the given error...

What to do now? Is it the normal behavior of next export command?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can refer to the tutorial to redeploy your application, and then revisit the page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556758/how-to-deploy-react-next-js-on-iis

Comment: @TheobaldDu Thanks! But I dont want to use any node server like iisnode. I want to deploy it like a static site

Comment: Is it the same URL but in a different way there will be different effects in the URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you need to check if there is any redirect/rewrite rule in your IIS or in your backend code. I test click "Chart" on home page, the url in browser will go to `https://beta.amarstock.com/chart`, but I found it request another url in fact as below screenshot show:

[image]

According to the screenshot above, we can find it request `https://www.amarstock.com/Chart/draw...` in fact. So if you input the url `https://beta.amarstock.com/chart` into browser directly, it will show 404 not found (please also pay attention to the case `Chart` and `chart`).

So I guess it may exists a logic which will redirect/rewrite to the url `https://www.amarstock.com/Chart/draw...` or in IIS url rewrite rule. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure rewrite rules to access pages directly.

Please take a look at this [article](https://dev.to/zaff/how-to-properly-deploy-a-static-html-site-built-by-nextjs-on-iis-to-avoid-404s-1pce) of mine about deploying a static html website built by next.js on IIS where you'll find how to accomplish this.